# Typewriter glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've the following code for typewriter in which the words are typed when user scrolls to the second section. Everything is going fine except some words are not being typed out smoothly. How can I remove this glitch?

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRygbV)

```js
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $("section:nth-of-type(2)").offset().top - 20) {
    // array with texts to type in typewriter
    var dataText = [
      "Amsterdam.",
      "Full Service.",
      "Webdevelopment.",
      "Wij zijn Occhio!"
    ];

    // type one text in the typwriter
    // keeps calling itself until the text is finished
    function typeWriter(text, i, fnCallback) {
      // chekc if text isn't finished yet
      if (i < text.length) {
        // add next character to h1
        document.querySelector("section:nth-of-type(2) h1").innerHTML =
          text.substring(0, i + 1) + '<span aria-hidden="true"></span>';

        // wait for a while and call this function again for next character
        setTimeout(function() {
          typeWriter(text, i + 1, fnCallback);
        }, 100);
      } else if (typeof fnCallback == "function") {
        // text finished, call callback if there is a callback function
        // call callback after timeout
        setTimeout(fnCallback, 700);
      }
    }
    // start a typewriter animation for a text in the dataText array
    function StartTextAnimation(i) {
      if (typeof dataText[i] == "undefined") {
        setTimeout(function() {
          StartTextAnimation(0);
        }, 20000);
      }
      // check if dataText[i] exists
      if (i < dataText[i].length) {
        // text exists! start typewriter animation
        typeWriter(dataText[i], 0, function() {
          // after callback (and whole text has been animated), start next text
          StartTextAnimation(i + 1);
        });
      }
    }
    // start the text animation
    StartTextAnimation(0);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FF5A5A;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'tradegothiclt-bold', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

span {
  border-right: .05em solid;
  animation: caret 1s steps(1) infinite;
}

@keyframes caret {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}

section{
  height:600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h1>Hallo, Wij zijn Occhio!</h1>
</section>  
<section>
  <h1>Hallo, Wij zijn Occhio!</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: It's getting lots of errors in the console. Maybe you should fix those problems first.

Comment: You're starting the animation every time the user scrolls to the second page, even if the animation is already running. So you end up with lots of simultaneous animations.

Comment: @Barmar How can I fix that?

Comment: Set a variable that indicates whether you've started the animation. if it's set, don't start the animation again.